# DHCP server clock isn't sync with current date; would it affect leases with a 0 (infinite) duration?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have a question regarding DHCP server where the clock of the server isn't set to the current date?

All the leases are set to infinite, now when the DHCP server time is synced using NTP to the current date the leases assigned to the clients are expired. New leases are granted to the clients after the server time reset, as the lease expiration was set to 0 or infinite, should the NTP syncing the clock affect the lease?

If the lease was set to a specific duration, I can understand but for infinite should the server reset?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Did you perhaps use a translation tool to help you post in english? If so, could you try using a different tool and see if that helps make things more clear? Or, if you didn't please re-read what you've posted and consider how you can make it more clear.

Comment: Im not sure what exactly wasnt clear, all Im trying to ask is if DHCP server clock isn't synced with the current date, after resetting the clock would it impact the leases that are granted to the clients with infinite period?

Comment: Its quite possible that that is a side-effect of the coding in it.  But why would you use infinite lease?  Use static ip addresses instead, thats what they are there for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will affect everything on that server till the point where DC marks him as out of sync and decides to stop delegating anything from it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/maximum-tolerance-for-computer-clock-synchronization

As of how,...well thats more of a "test and trial" part, cus there is no reason to leave any computer(even less server) out of sync with rest of servers(be it homelab or enterprise surroundings) that it has to communicate with. I doubt you will find clear answer on this, but I can tell you, nothing good will come out of it :)